# Error Generating R shiny dashboard: Warning: Error in choicesWithNames

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build my first R shiny dashboard. I am facing an issue with generating the dashboard. I get below error when I am trying to run the code below. I have over 10 times looked at my code I couldn't find any error and also R doesn*t provide the error mark in the index. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Error:

```
Warning: Error in choicesWithNames: argument "choices" is missing, with no default
  84: hasGroups
  83: choicesWithNames
  82: selectInput
```

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(elo)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel(title = "Project 1"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Jahr", "Select Year"))),
    
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                    tabPanel("Data", shiny::dataTableOutput("df1")),
                    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summ")),
                    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("Plot"))
  ))
))


Server:

shinyServer(function(input, output){
    # Return the formula text for printing as a Patienten Daten
    output$df1 <- shiny::renderDataTable({
        
        df1
        
    })
    output$summ <- renderprint({
        summary(df1)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(df1, aes(x=Jahr)) +
            stat_count(geom = 'line', aes(y=..count..),color = "#0099f9", size = 1)+
            stat_count(geom = "point", color = "#0099f9", size = 2) +
            geom_text(aes(label=..count..),stat="count",position=position_stack(), size = 3, vjust=1.6) +
            labs(title = "Jährliche Veröffentlichungen seit 2010", subtitle = "zum Themenkomplex Digital Health Interventions", y = "Häufigkeit", x = "Veröffentlichungsjahr")
    })
})
```

Comment: `selectInput`'s first three arguments, the third of which is `choices`, have no defaults.  In your definition of `input$Jahr`, you've supplied only two.  The clue is in the error message.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!! But I have a different error  ```Warning: Error in renderprint: could not find function "renderprint" ``` for that I have to open a different post I guess.

Comment: There was a typo instead of renderPrint I typed renderprint in the code. I dont have to open a diffent post.